# AngularJS .length returns a TypeError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, console, angularjs-filter

I'm performing a very routine task in my Filter to check if

```
    angular.module('someApp')
     .filter('filterSomeData',['$filter',function ($filter) {
      return function (items, keyObj) {
    var filterObj = {
      data:items,
      filteredData:[],
      applyFilter : function(query,key){
        var fData = [];
        //unfiltered data at the start
        if(this.filteredData.length === 0){
          this.filteredData = this.data;
        }
        if(query){              
          var fObj = {};         
          if(!angular.isArray(query)){
            fObj[key] = query;
            angular.forEach(fObj, function(fObj, i){
                    fData = fData.concat(
                      $filter('filter')
                      (this.filteredData,fObj));
                }, this);
            console.log(this.filteredData);
          }
          else if(angular.isArray(query)){
            console.log(query);
            if(query.length > 0){ 
              for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
                if(angular.isDefined(query[i])){
                  fObj[key] = query[i];
                  angular.forEach(fObj, function(fObj, i){
                          fData = fData.concat(
                            $filter('filter')
                            (this.filteredData,fObj));
                      }, this);
                }
              }

            }                   
          }                 
          if(fData.length > 0){
            this.filteredData = fData;
          }
          else{
            this.filteredData;
          }
        }
      }
  };

  if(keyObj){
    angular.forEach(keyObj,function(query,key){
      filterObj.applyFilter(query,key);          
    });     
  }

  return filterObj.filteredData;      
}
```

}])

But in my console it fires an error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Even if we assume this.filteredData isn't defined at the time when checked, I cannot understand why `.length` fires an error.

The functionality isn't affected at all but I want to make sure my console is clean.

Any ideas?

*Update:*
Diving deeper into the code, it looks like the filters are applied **before** the AJAX call is complete. Initially filterObj is undefined and then populates as soon as the data is loaded. Is there a way to delay the injection of filters until the data is loaded, like a promise?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: please can you post the complete code. The snippet is to small. The context around is missing.

Comment: well,  where do you define the variabe obj?

Comment: @basilikum I'm initializing `filteredData: []` in `filterObj` ?

Comment: What i meant was, that there is another place where a try to access the length property: `obj.length`. `obj` doesn't seem to be defined though. So are you sure, that the error occurs where you suspect it to occur? Or could it be that this is the problem?

Comment: I have typeErrors on `line 14: if(this.filteredData.length === 0) ` 
`line 55-56:         angular.forEach(keyObj,function(query,key){
          filterObj.applyFilter(query,key); `
The code works just as expected.

Comment: @SinSync hey did you find solution for this issue? I am struck exactly on same place :(

Answer (score 1):

> Even if we assume this.filteredData isn't defined at the time when
>   checked, I cannot understand why .length fires an error.

If you try to access a property on an object that is not defined, then you get this type error. Try this at the console:

```
a = {b:'four'}
a.b.length
4
a.c.length
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Therefore if this.filteredData does not exist, you cannot access the length property.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I'm already initializing the values. So is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: From the additional code you've added to the question, it does look like you've initialized this.filteredData. You access length in several places throughout your code, are you sure that this is the line that the console is complaining about?

Comment: It's firing an error on every instance. I have multiple TypeErrors(5) as a result. I'm using angular 1.3.9. maybe it's something to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

I world find out why the element is undefined, and maybe declare it AS an empty object or array somewhere before the If statement.

Comment: Hello Sir, I'm already doing that in `filterObj`, initializing `filteredData: [ ]`